# Do I need to pay for a Transfer Code to withdraw funds from account?

Tags: fraud, withdrawal

Do I have to pay a transfer fee to complete my withdrawal to receive a transfer code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/5406