# Blockchain.com payments

Tags: blockchain.info, payment

Need some assistance if I need to stop and take my losses. I had Bitcoin mined and the earned profits. I paid the commission fee and the profit was moved to blockchain.com. They requested a payment of $3500 because it’s a new wallet. Unfortunately I didn’t pay it timely due to purchase limits only cash app and coinbase accounts. I paid the $3500. But then they said Bec of the delay i had to pay an additional $2000. Yes I paid that and now they are saying I need to pay $3500 again within 3-4 days.  Is this normal process?  Please help!

Comment: No, you're being scammed, see e.g. this related topic: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103011/5406

Comment: If your next question is [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866) there are lots of questions and helpful answers on this website. Don't trust PMs from or about "recovery experts".

Comment: Is it even possible to recover?

Comment: It's very unlikely, the money is probably gone.

Comment: Thanks Murch! I’ll take this loss and learn from it. Glad I came here to ask before digging myself deeper!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a common process used by scammers. It ends up in you paying them lots to withdraw your money that has never been yours without receiving even 1 cent from them.

Don't write to them but seek help from your local authorities.