# If someone with a business account wants to send me bitcoin, do I need a minimum deposit in my wallet?

Tags: fraud

If they have a business account with a high amount in it, do I need a minimum of £550 in mine for them to be able to transfer?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/5406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, anything claiming something like this is a scam.