# I have received £46,21745 in my Bitcoin account. Should I confirm it?

Tags: confirmations, spam, email

I don't have a Bitcoin account (I never made one), but I got an email  that I have received £46,21745 in my account and my first payment is ready for my confirmation. I would like to know how Bitcoin account works before I confirm it. I need to confirm it within 48 hours or my account will be closed.
[image: email]

Comment: This is most definitely a scam. Just ignore it.

Comment: They can't even make up their mind which currency it's valued in: dollars, pounds or euros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **I don't have any Bitcoin account [...] but I got an email that I have received £46,21745 in my account**

It is a lie. There's no money. It is a trick by criminals who will
later ask you to pay some fake fees that they invent.

After you realise you have been tricked, some other person (criminals also, maybe the same ones) will then contact you to offer fake recovery services. They too will trick you out of more money.

See

- [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/13866)
- [fraud](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fraud)
- [non-spendable](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=non-spendable)
- [watch-only](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=watch-only)

Comment: And/or the "confirm" link will be malware.