# Do Bitcoin deposits happen in 3 phases?

Tags: mining-reward

I recently had someone convert my sumcoin and said they were going to send to my Bitcoin wallet. I noticed that about $150 (of the $57,000) came through. He said that deposits of that size occur in 3 phases. I got the first two. The second would require me to send 0.059717 Bitcoin to "be paid by the investor directly to the blockchain technology, activation wallet address "
bitcoin:

bc1q5tx6vnhtr4ewwup246fe3xs6kgwrhql4l5xnp2

When I google that wallet it doesnt come back to anyone and appears to have around 41 transactions against it. Here is what the rest of his text says, "and as soon as it is recieved by the wallet the coins are automatically activated.

And YOUR FULL AMOUNT WILL SHOW ON YOUR BITCOIN WALLET ADDRESS SAME WAY THE $50 and $100 showed up

Note : THE 0.059717 Bitcoin is simply for activation and release purposes of your balance sent coins and you are to fund it into the blockchain technology activation wallet .  To avoid a reversion there’s usually a 14 business days limit placed on it

So ensure to have it funded within the next 14 business days to avoid the coins being held up completely

Thank you
We are here to provide the very best blockchain technology
Customer support"

When I asked him to give me the customer support info he was very stand-offish. Said the way he converted was proprietary. I said I dont care how he did it... I want to make sure this "Customer support" is real.
Has anyone else gone through anything like this?
thanks!
-Blake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal). The person you entrusted your money to seems to be talking nonsense. There are no activation fees. I am certain you have been scammed. Any money you sent is stolen. You can report this to local police but you will almost certainly never get any of your money back.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. If there is some place that is asking for some fee (I know there are mining fees of some sort with the blockchain) they should be able to tell me who is asking so I could verify. They refuse to tell me. They are also pressing pretty hard for a commission.  When I asked why they just didnt withdraw that before sending my BTC they said they forgot. Oh well... lesson learned. Thanks!