# Can sent bitcoin be reverted?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, transaction-fees

Can succesfully sent bitcoin be reverted? The reason was that a fee was needed. The fee will be sent back after transfer is fulfilled?!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal). No, Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed/undone/cancelled/reverted. Any advance fee is a certain sign of fraud by a confidence-trickster (conman/thief)

Comment: I think RedGrittyBrick has pointed you in the right direction. If we misunderstood your question please provide more information and vote for reopening.