# Upgrading fee in bitcoin

Tags: transaction-fees

The guy who is mining my account is saying he needs an upgrading fee of $100 to withdraw my profit of $2000 is it not a scam

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a scam. "Mining my account", "needs an upgrade fee", neither of these things make any sense. Cut your losses, do not send the scammer anymore money.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal) -- There is no such thing as an "upgrading fee" in the Bitcoin network and this is 100% a scam.