# I set up a Trust wallet do I need bitcoin in there to receive bitcoin

Tags: fraud

I set up a trust wallet put 5k in it as was told I needed this much in it to receive my investment (bitcoin)but the 5k is not accessible as now they say I need 7k more to make it accessible I am assured a payout (only the person I have been talking with)but I have sent 1000s initially

Comment: This is with bitnextradefx so if anyone can help as if they are a fraud set up please advise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal)

Comment: Definitely a scam. All the money is gone and cannot be recovered. Contact your local police. Do not give any more money to the scammer and don't communicate with them. Do not put money into that wallet

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need any BTC funds to be able to receive BTC in your wallet.

Schemes where you have to prepare/provide some funds 'in order' to receive something else sound very much like a scam.