# Can the exchange rate fee be taken from the payment amount?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have a pending payment from Bitcoin Bonus but to withdraw have to pay a exchange rate fee cant the fee just be taken from payment amount and sent to my wallet?

Comment: Yes. So you found a scam!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal).  So far every question here that mentions "bitcoin bonus" looks like it is a complete scam.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the "fee scam". Don't fall for it.