# I received an email saying I have money from "Bitcoin bonus"

Tags: fraud

I received an email that stated that I had $22000 that I have to withdraw out a bitcoin bonus mining I guess and I don't know how to do that how do I withdraw my money

Comment: 110% a scam, there's no email with bitcoin

Answer (score 3):

There is a widespread scam which mentions Bitcoin bonus and the initial email is usually followed by a demand for a fee such as $64, to release a payment, often $22000.

It is a scam, ignore it and do not pay any fees.

See

- [Questions about "Bitcoin bonus" (local search)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=Bitcoin%20bonus)
- [Questions about "Bitcoin bonus" (Google search)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bitcoin+bonus%22+site%3Abitcoin.stackexchange.com)
- [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/13866)