# How do I get to the bitcoin mining website, I have funds in my account that I need to withdraw!

Tags: mining-pools

How do I get to the website for Bitcoin mining I need to withdraw my bitcoins !!

Answer (score 4):

Bitcoin was designed to be used without websites.

There is no single website for Bitcoin or for Bitcoin mining.

Mining Bitcoin nowadays requires special equipment and I don't know of any genuine business that provides mining as a service.

See

- [I received an email saying I have money from "Bitcoin bonus"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116057/13866)
- [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/13866)