# Bitcoin confirmation

Tags: confirmations

How to finish up conformation process on bitcoin[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal)

Answer (score 2):

This is a scam.

**In the real Bitcoin network, confirmation of transactions happens without the recipient of the money needing to do anything.**

Asking you to pay money to a "confirmation address" is, to me, a clear sign of fraud.

I believe the web site you are using, or the email you have received, is fraudulent and that you have been tricked by criminals.

My advice is

- Do not send any money to that "confirmation address".
- Report fraud to your local police
- If you already paid money, do not expect to ever get it back. Move on with your life.
- Do not engage with anyone offering recovery services. Because you have been tricked once, criminals view you as a prime target for further trickery and theft.