# Fraud funds in blockchain account

Tags: fraud

A company called currentcoins.net has taken money from ZOPA in my name.  They have placed the funds in a Blockchain account.  I have the trackable evidence of the funds being moved into this account.  How do I get the funds back from this blockchain account? P.S the Account with blockchain is not my account.

Comment: Do you have some sort of agreement with this company? The whois lookup shows that the domain you mentioned was only registered a few months ago, that along with the rest of your post leads me to think you are being scammed in some way.

Comment: See for example: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal

Answer (score 2):

ZOPA is a UK bank. If someone took money out of your bank account, you must tell the bank and report the theft to police.

If you took the money out yourself and paid it to some business, it is probably not something anyone else can fix for you