# Can any one tell me is this a scammer they told me to pay 80 dolar

Tags: transaction-fees

They told me to pay 80 dolar to activate is this a scammer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal) -- yes, you are being scammed.