# Private Investment Company - BTC wallet

Tags: fraud, investing

Good evening,does anybody know or ever heard about NEXFORD CAPITAL Private Investment Company ([www.nexfordcapital.com](http://www.nexfordcapital.com)) based in London? Is the company legit and reliable to invest in? Please advice. Thank you

Comment: Website claims founded 2016 but domain first registered 2022-06-14. No UK company registration number shown, There is no UK registered company with that name. Street address is a provider of "virtual offices".

Comment: Thank u very much for replying my Q, I have my money freezed in their investment machine, I can't withdraw instead they asked me to pay $1,750 to obtain an "ID Card" so I can make withdrawal. I don't trust them. What should I do now? I think I have been scammed. Please advice. Thank you

Comment: @KsimHlim unfortunately, cut your losses and move on. It sounds like you have fallen victim to an 'advance fee scam'. See: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me advice on this matter, it really stressed me out all this time. Yeah I have to move on, no such things in this world is too good to be true. If maybe you have other trustworthy investment platform may share with me. Thank you.

Comment: May we make this issues viral to the public so that no other victims are entangled with their rotten offers. Please advice. Thank you

Comment: @KsimHlim re: *"If maybe you have other trustworthy investment platform may share with me. Thank you"*:   Don't trust; verify.