# Help in bitcoins

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app

I made a withdrawal request on the free crypto website. Where and how can I follow up on the problem? WITHDRAWAL HISTORY WALLET ADDRESS : TJQ14QQ6RCcRH4EYm3JyhnQMhHfni33dwv AMOUN : 0.35672 ВТС Date : Jul 29, 2023 06:49 PM Status: Under Review

Comment: If you have a problem with your account at some business, only that specific business can help you. Any site that promises free crypto is almost certainly some kind of scam. The address in your question is not a proper Bitcoin address. Don't pay them any withdrawal fees, don't top up your account to a minimum withdrawal level. Dont pay any transaction or transfer fees - all examples of lies frequently seen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal)