# I raised my bitcoin to 0.02 but it should be 0.05 when I withdraw, why?

Tags: withdrawal

I raised my bitcoin to 0.02, but when I withdraw, it shows the withdrawal amount as 0.05, I can't withdraw?

Comment: Hi Yazdan, it sounds like you are experiencing some issues with a specific company. We are just some random Bitcoin enthusiasts on the internet that don’t have insight into the inner workings of specific companies. However, that 0.05 ₿ is a pretty big chunk of money, and way more than usual for minimum withdrawals. Have you acquired those bitcoins suspiciously affordable and they are trying to get you to deposit more money with them so you can withdraw?

Comment: I reached the value of 0.02 bitcoins from the btcfree.win site, which previously said that this range can be withdrawn, but today the value of 0.05 bitcoins is the permitted withdrawal range.

Comment: That’s about 600 USD. That sounds like a lot of winnings for a presumably free website. I would suspect that it’s an [advance fee scam](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/5406): they’ll probably keep raising the minimum withdrawal until you deposit money to reach the minimum withdrawal amount and then abscond with it.

Comment: A brief websearch into the legitimacy of that site has a bunch of “is this a scam” hits.

Comment: There is no place to deposit money on the site, if it is a scam, they will probably hack the wallet

Comment: What is your overall opinion? Does it seem like a scam?

Comment: I count four red flags: 1) Changing withdrawal conditions, 2) Promises money for free, 3) Lots of people asking all over the internet whether it’s a scam, 4) Four other websites with very similar names pop up on the first page of the search engine,… Basically whenever it’s not obvious how a service is supposed to make money, it’s very likely a scam. And it’s not clear to me at all how they’d turn a profit on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice

Comment: If it’s not an advance fee scam, they may simply be farming ad revenue by having people come back over and over again without ever paying anything out.