# Who pays the fees for a node payment?

Tags: nodes, payment

Is it true that the recipient has to pay the fees of a node payment upfront or the transaction won't go through?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/5406?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not true.

Anyone asking for upfront fees is a criminal trying to trick you and steal your money. A swindler. A scammer. A confidence trickster or conman.

Comment: There is also no such thing as a "node payment".

Comment: The transaction is the payment. There isn't some other payment other than the payment.