# New, trading, scam?

Tags: fraud

(Google translation - see edit history for Q in Georgian script)

hello I made an invitation to Bitcoin with the help of a trader. Now the trader tells me that it is necessary to withdraw the full profit, but since the profit is big ($26000) I have to pay $255, otherwise the platform will not accept it. He also tells me that the account where the profit is placed is registered to my email and name, but he does not tell me which platform and stubbornly asks me for the money. payment. All this makes me think that I am a victim of fraud, now the question is, is it possible to find out where and on which platform my email was used to find out where my profit is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal)