# Refunding Bitcoin Sieged stolen funds Blockchain.com

Tags: wallet-recovery, fraud

I am a novice to Bitcoin Stuff. Can someone advise me please? I bought Bitcoin around 2011. This was via a company on line.
I have been told by different groups over the phone (maybe 5 different callers in two years). that the Company was closed by a regulation body and the funds held. Now a new company (+49 1522 565 2168, Finanzabteilung
Blockchain Frankfurt, An d. Welle 4
60322 Frankfurt am Main
Deutschland Blockchain.com) Now if I want the funds back.....I must create a new wallet to put the funds into. I created one with Atomic Wallet.( It seems a secure wallet) This Blockchain.com wants me to put $2K in this wallet because the Australia (where I live) needs to see Transactions in the wallet before depositing the funds in an Australian Bank.
I Know that even HSBC and ING Orange cannot except funds from Cripto or over seas Banks with out Government Questions,   How would this scam work when the wallet is in my name, with my image and my password??

Comment: Hi Clemesha, this sounds like someone might be trying to pull the [Advance Fee Scam](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/5406) on you. You should never need to pay money to someone in order for them to send your money to you. If they have your money, they can deduct any fees from that and send you the rest.