# I have bitcoin sitting in Muskxmoon and i’m trying to withdraw it to a card or bank or something where i can have the money itself. please help

Tags: withdrawal, money

I have been trying to find a way to try and get this money (BTC) into my account or get a hold of the money. i’m sorta new to this and don’t know what to do to use this money like if i wanted to buy shoes or something. Is there anyway i can get a hold of this into my hands?

Comment: Numerous red flags suggest that the mentioned website muskxmoon dot com may be untrustworthy: the domain was only created a month ago, its site title ambiguously reads "Just a moment...", and online discussions questioning its legitimacy are prevalent. Given these signs, it's highly probable that it is a scam. Exercise extreme caution when interacting with them. Depositing ₿ or other forms of currency could result in permanent loss, as retrieval is unlikely.

Comment: Also, just as deyw already mentioned, if you have a balance there, do not ever send more money for them to allow a withdrawal. If they have your money, they could deduct any fees from that balance. Also see: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/5406