# Is it real BTC or fake

Tags: blockchain, wallet, json-rpc, network, testnet

All,

I received some BTC to my coinbase wallet after someone asked me to setup custom network using the below setting. I received the BTC but I couldn't transfer to any other wallet and the says invalid BTC address. Am I scammed? Network name: Bitcoin RPC URL: https://testnet-rpc.satoshichain.io Chain ID: 5758 Currency Symbol: BTC Block Explorer URL: https://www.blockchain.com/explorer

Any help is much appreciated. The person who sent me this wants me to send money so he can validate the wallet address.

Is this true?

I'm not going to pay anymore but want to know if the BTC he moved to my wallet is real or fake. I read that any cypto sent using testnet doesn't have any real value. The guy used testnet-rep.satoshichain network so please tell me if this is fake or real BTC

Comment: Testnet BTC is worthless. You are being scammed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so I guess the URL he used is a testnet URL? it says testnet on there but just wanted to confirm. He is keep saying that the BTC he sent was real. He says there are many ways the BTC can be transferred that I don;t understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal)

Answer (score 0):

Excactly the same with you.
I received from someone BTC and gave me the same details..
Same name ,same rpc url ,same chain id,same currency symbol and same block explorer url..I can’t transfer BTC to any other wallet..he says that I must verification my wallet but I did already this..Maybe have the same scammer..