# Is this fraud by chance

Tags: fraud

[image]
This is a email I got think it's fraud

Comment: Thank u so much I truly appreciate you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its a fraud. You would need specialised equipment to earn that kind of money. Also the 24-hour deadline is a typical ruse by criminals to panic their victims into acting without taking time to think about what they are doing.

The last line suggests advance fee fraud - [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103891/13866)

Comment: This is the crypto version of the Nigerian Prince scam. I have $40 million dollars for you but you have to send me $50k first so I can send it to you. Fraud....fraud never changes.