Trying to do a withdrawal on bit coin out of wallet
I invested 1000.00 in Bitcoin 6 months ago and was told I could withdraw some and leave some so I elected to withdraw 10 k and have paid fees and taxes and more fees totaling around 3000.00.  Guess I'm asking did I fall for a scam

To answer this question requires more information. Such as where you invested etc ..

Does https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal answer your question?
